# Group two column and distinct

Tags: php, mysql

I tried this code to output this (Correct Output)

[image]

But it gave me this which is wrong output
[image]

I need to distinct the name and group the item by brand but it did not happen in my query see the picture above.

```
$datefilter=mysqli_query($link,"select 
        SUM(INVOICE_ITEM_AMOUNT_MX) AS totalamount,
        INVOICE_NO_MX,
        INVOICE_CUSTOMER_NAME
        ,INVOICE_DATE_MX,ITEM_BRAND_MX
        ,GROUP_CONCAT(INVOICE_ITEM_CODE_MX SEPARATOR '<BR>') as itemcode 
            ,GROUP_CONCAT(INVOICE_ITEM_QTY_MX SEPARATOR '<BR>') as quantity 
            ,GROUP_CONCAT(INVOICE_ITEM_UPRICE_MX SEPARATOR '<BR>') as price 
            ,GROUP_CONCAT(INVOICE_ITEM_SERIAL_MX SEPARATOR '<BR>') as serial 
                    ,GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT (INVOICE_SALES_REP_MX) SEPARATOR '<BR>') as salesrep 

            ,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT (ITEM_BRAND_MX) SEPARATOR '<BR>') as brand         
    from invoice where INVOICE_DATE_MX BETWEEN '" .$datefrom. "' AND  '" . $dateto ."' and 
    BRANCH_CODE_MX='".$display_branchcode."' AND INVOICE_STATUS_MX='PAID' GROUP BY INVOICE_SALES_REP_MX,ITEM_BRAND_MX ");

     $count=mysqli_num_rows($datefilter);
        echo '<div class="col-xs-12">

                    <br>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
    <label> Total Invoice Number: </label> '.$count.'
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
    <label> Date Range: </label> '.$convertedfrom.' - '.$convertedto.'
        </div>
        </div>';            

        while($daterow=mysqli_fetch_array($datefilter)){
                                    $date=$daterow["INVOICE_DATE_MX"];
                            $customername=$daterow["INVOICE_CUSTOMER_NAME"];
                            $invoiceref=$daterow["INVOICE_NO_MX"];
                            $salesrep=$daterow["salesrep"];
                            $itemcode=$daterow["itemcode"];
                            $imeiserial=$daterow["serial"];
                            $totalnotformat=$daterow["totalamount"];
                            $upricenotformat=$daterow["price"];
                            $quantity=$daterow["quantity"];
                            $itembrand=$daterow["brand"];

                      $total=number_format($totalnotformat,2);
                      $uprice=number_format($upricenotformat,2);            
        echo'
    <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <br>
                    <div class="panel panel-warning">
        <div id="shade" class="panel-body"><label>'.$salesrep.'</label></div>
        <div  id="shade" class="panel-body">
    <div class="col-xs-10">
    <div class="col-xs-4">';
    echo '
    <label>Brand</label>: '.$itembrand.'<br>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
    <label>Item Code</label> <br>'.$itemcode.'  

    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">
    <label> Quantity</label> <br>'.$quantity.'  

    </div>
    </div>             
    </div>        
        </div>
```

Comment: A good way to ask a MySQL question is to show input data, query, and expected output, along with your current output.

Comment: a correct query to my problem :(

Comment: i already give it

Comment: Your code is really a little messy! Can you please format it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, the following should help and what you wanted I mean to show distinct names. But you could do it with PHP easily:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t.id = (SELECT t2.id FROM process t2
WHERE t2.projectNo = t.projectNo
GROUP BY t2.projectNo LIMIT 1) THEN t.projectNo
ELSE
''
END AS Deatils, t.stuff
FROM process t
```

Sample input and output:

[image: mysql_distinct]

[image: mysql_distinct_02]

Comment: I guess, you have a single table. Just use the primary key of that table and change columns according to yours.